# VSCode Permission issues for File creation and Renaming in a Django App

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I'm having an issue with creating another python file inside of the main app of my Django tree (I'm still learning Django so I'm not sure of the terminology). When I try to create a file inside of main part of the app named tweets I get this error.

```
Unable to write file '/Users/ak/Dev/tweetme/tweets/forms.py' (NoPermissions 
(FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied, open
```

Then I said fine, I'll just create the file in another directory and move it to the tweets folder, When I attempt this, I get the following error.

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename 
'/Users/ak/Dev/tweetme/tweetme/forms.py' -> 
'/Users/ak/Dev/tweetme/tweets/forms.py'
```

From what I can read only people having this issues have downloaded some SSH shelling mod, which I don't have, nor do I know what that is. This problem came on suddenly, When I started this project I had no problem created files inside of the tweets folder. Does anyone have any insight into this?? Or how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using WSL? Can you try to upgrade it to WSL2?

You can also empower the folder directly with this command:

```
sudo chown -R username /path/to/working/directory
```

And you can also open the VSCode with 'Run as Administrator'.

Comment: I have the same problem on native Ubuntu, and running VSCode as admin is not an option